# test all JUnit files from all packages in TestNG

Tags: java, xml, junit, testng

Lets say I have alot of packages and I want to test every JUnit file inside each of all packages.
Do I need to specify all the packages so that they will actually be tested?
Or can I skip that part so that it will run all the files inside of writing each package name inside the packages tag?

```
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

    <!-- $Id$ -->

    <suite name="client" verbose="1">
      <test name="client-all" junit="false">
        <groups>
          <run>
            <include name="unit"/>
            <exclude name="broken"/>
          </run>
        </groups>
<!-- Do I really need to specify all the package names? What if I have alot
and want to run on all of them? -->
          <packages>
            <package name="seriously?"/>
          </packages>
      </test>
    </suite>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use wildcards in package definition. So something like:

```
<packages>
    <package name="com.myRootPackage.*"/>
</packages>
```

match all packages starting with `com.myRootPackage`